# How to extract part of string in batch file (substring between two characters)

Tags: batch-file

I need to retrieve a value from the registry (a "session ID" for software called "Connectwise".

I am using REG QUERY as follows:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\ScreenConnect Client 
(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)" /v Path
```

This gives me:

> ```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\ScreenConnect Client (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)\ScreenConnect.ClientService.exe" "?e=Access&y=Guest&s=cfd090d2-2d40-4ee9-be4e-4e32bc47b603&h=myScreenConnectServer.com&p=8041&k=BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAgAAAEAAQAJk9uDKzh99oEYFTDvWDpBsTcwlb%2b22BTXk8U4G1m0wDIkT%2bCUn6FcJ1cefwcCnjZjIZauhull4TtZAlEtg7FdQUtRFUKd88kf8H9bZd0Don0PDvHiq7q8eG4Tqe59eOGxrEyFKIxz%2fTGlgVgZZARzz7glYHDC7TUQySSscP%2fW7sXZ74ees4vPn%2fug24tZHaElz6KR2y0%2bLrljF37b4Lkv%2bK56%2bmhMwCvLAmHUie6aRFEablDPJQAa6u9%2fViYRfd2tv0Shqc5sqKBSuU26L0Q1Orhu4t6WMIjVQR1ikRZSVrOStz8JQOk%2bVoJ6omt2Uem0LQORSzRHlKazgtl%2fizi8&t=&c="
> ```

I now need to trim what's being returned to only include the 36 characters after "&s=", i.e.

> ```
> cfd090d2-2d40-4ee9-be4e-4e32bc47b603
> ```

I'm a bit lost as to where to go next with this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The general method would be to run the command inside a [tag:for-loop] with the `/F` option and parse the returned value. A better method would be to use a scripting language which would better perform the substring process but based upon your tags, that falls outside of your defined question parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using Powershell.